# Android.mk - what toolchain used by default?

Tags: android, android-ndk, toolchain

What toolchain used by default when compile through Android.mk ?
And how change the toolchain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default toolchain was *gcc-4.6* for a long time. It has changed to *gcc-4.8* in the NDK *r10d* version (currently the latest version).

You can choose to use another toolchain through modifying the `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION` variable, through`ndk-build` call (example: `ndk-build NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang3.4`, or by setting it inside *Application.mk* file. Example:

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang3.4
```