# Android CMake stack size

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, clang

in CMake there is a possibility to increase stack size by such command:

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG} /STACK:10485760")
```

How can i reach the same for a SHARED library?

`set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} /STACK:10485760")`

and

`set(CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS} /STACK:10485760")` 
not working.

**#EDIT1**

Android uses clang++ linker.
And i cannot found any info in official docs how to increase stack size.

Comment: Isn't `/STACK` for Microsoft's linker? Which toolchain are you using to build your shared library?

Comment: @Michael, arm and x86

Comment: I meant the *toolchain* (as in LLVM, GCC, ...), not the ABI.

Comment: @Michael, i guestt gcc or clang related to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29396637/android-mk-what-toolchain-used-by-default